# How to create a type that takes some generic so that a list of objects can infer values from the generic

Tags: typescript

```
type PropsFormatter<T> = // What should this be so that the format params below are inferred from T values as described

const obj = { wheels: ["good", "bad", "great", "new"], lights: 2, doors: "new", min: 2, max: 100 };

const config: PropsFormatter<typeof obj> = [
  {
    prop: "doors",
    format: (doors) => `${doors}`,
    // doors is inferred as a string
  },
  {
    prop: "wheels",
    format: (wheels) => `${wheels}`,
    // wheels is inferred as string[]
  },
  {
    prop: "lights",
    format: (lights) => `${lights}`,
    // lights is inferred as number
  },
  {
    prop: ["min", "max"],
    format: (min, max) => `${min}-${max}`,
    // min is inferred as number and max is inferred as number
  },
]);
```

I've currently solved it like this

```
const obj = { wheels: ["good", "bad", "great", "new"], lights: 2, doors: "new", min: 2, max: 100 };

type StringKeys<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
type CombinedProp<T, LK extends StringKeys<T>[]> = { 
  props: [...LK], 
  format:(...val: { 
    [I in keyof LK]: T[LK[I]] 
  }) => string 
}
type PropsFormatter<T,K extends StringKeys<T>, LK extends StringKeys<T>[]> =
| (K extends StringKeys<T> ? { prop: K; format:(val: T[K])  => string}  : never)
| CombinedProp<T,LK>;

const makeConfig = <T,K extends StringKeys<T>, LK extends StringKeys<T>[]> (params: T, config: PropsFormatter<T, K, LK>[]) => {
  return config
}

makeConfig(obj, [
  {
    prop: "doors",
    format: (doors) => `${doors}`,
  },
  {
    prop: "wheels",
    format: (wheels) => `${wheels}`,
  },
  {
    prop: "lights",
    format: (lights) => `${lights}`,
  },
  {
    props: ["min", "max"],
    format: (min, max) => `${min}-${max}`,
  },
]);
```

But I don't understand why I need to have a function `makeConfig` that takes the first argument only to get the type, instead of being able to create a type that just takes the type as a generic.

Comment: Uh... there's no (scalable) specific type if `prop` can be an array of every possible permutation of sets of keys of the type.  Do you have a reasonable limit for how many elements a `prop` array might have?

Comment: I've updated the question with how I'm currently solving the problem but I'd prefer not to have to use a function but no sure if that's possible.

Comment: Even the [non-scalable version](https://tsplay.dev/mbQQBN) doesn't give you inference for the members where `prop` is an array, since arrays are not union discriminants.  My suggestion here would have been to use a helper function (or a builder) but since that's what you have already I'd say this is essentially not possible.  Shall I write up an answer explaining this?  Or am I missing something about what you want?

Comment: Re-reading your comment. I think it's just a limitation of typescript.  I have to use a helper function (incur runtime cost) to achieve static typing that I need. I'd rather not have to use the function and just provide type annotations to achieve this.

Comment: An explanation of why a helper function is needed would answer this question.